# How to fix MySQL only returning column name in query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in a MySQL database that works as a course grade book. I have the table set up so that the columns are students names and the rows are the assignment name. The data that goes in is the grade.

However the problem that i am having is when i try to select a student (column named after a student), it only return the name of the column repeated. 
Here is the query:

```
SELECT 'Ryan Wans' FROM cachedb.stewart;
```

Where Ryan Wans is the student name and stewart is the name of the table.
It returns the following:

```
+---------+
|Ryan Wans|
+---------+
|Ryan Wans|
|Ryan Wans|
|Ryan Wans|
|Ryan Wans|
+---------+
```

It Should Return:

```
+---------+
|Ryan Wans|
+---------+
|100      |
|87       |
|100      |
|96       |
+---------+
```

It returns 4 times because I have 4 assignments in the table.
The numbers represent the grades.
Any help is appreciated.

NOTE : I would also prefer to keep the student names as columns.

Comment: Try `Ryan Wans` - backtick instead of '

Comment: @MatthewPage Thanks very much, this worked!! Any idea as to why tho??

Comment: Your column name should never be someones name, that's really bad database design. Post your tables and we'll clean them up :)

Comment: The SELECT thinks anything in quotes is a text string , `SELECT 'hello world'` . Usually a column name has no spaces so you can just use the name with no quotes, the space forces you to use quotes, but in this case backticks

Comment: @MatthewPage Actually: How would you make the table more efficient?? any help is needed :)

Comment: I would start a new question, How to optimise my tables.. Explain what the data is you are storing and show the tables you have. If you tag it MySQL I'll drop in before the admins kill it for a code review :)

Comment: @MatthewPage Here is the table :) https://github.com/ryanrocket/tts-basic/blob/master/bin/testdb.txt

Comment: Great, give me a chance the practice my git commands, I'll try and edit it and you should get a notice...

Answer (score -1):

'Ryan Wans' should be your where condition.

Select * from cachedb.stewart 
where column_name = 'Ryan Wans'

Or instead of *, call whatever column name you wanna call after select i.e. amount, qty

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. The column name is actually called 'Ryan Wans' . Nice database modelling going on..

Comment: lol couldnt think that column name would be 'Ryan Wans'. Agree with u, nice db modelling :)

Comment: sorry im a noob :(

Comment: @RyanWans It amuses us because we've done it. A few concepts and you'll be modelling like a pro